# PHP json_encode and jQuery parseJSON not working

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to pass an array from PHP to jQuery.

php file. `$results` is an array

```
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($results));
```

jQuery

```
jQuery.post(url, data, function(response) {

                        var discount_obj = JSON.parse(response);
                        var discount_type = "";
                        var discount_amount = "";
                         $.each(discount_obj,function(index,item) {
                            if(index=="discount_type") {
                                discount_type = item;
                            }

                            if(index=="value") {
                                discount_amount = item;
                            }

                        });
});
```

I keep getting this error   `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`.

Here is the json returned

```
[  
   {  
      &quot;ID&quot;:&quot;4&quot;,
      &quot;code&quot;:&quot;test_code_3&quot;,
      &quot;description&quot;:&quot;&lt;p&gt;testing4&lt;\/p&gt;&quot;,
      &quot;value&quot;:&quot;100&quot;,
      &quot;type&quot;:&quot;discount&quot;,
      &quot;username&quot;:&quot;Mark&quot;,
      &quot;valid_from&quot;:&quot;09\/01\/2015&quot;,
      &quot;expires&quot;:&quot;10\/23\/2015&quot;
   }
]
```

how do i solve?

Comment: There's no way to know if you don't post here the result of the PHP file (the JS variable response)

Comment: Your PHP script is probably printing something else before it calls `json_encode`. Check the Network tab of the browser console to see the full response.

Comment: check edit.  i use htmlspecialchars because the `$results` array has p tags

Comment: What about your usage requires you to use `&quot` instead of just quotation marks?

Comment: Remove the htmlspecialchars or run that before you JSON encode